# Is there an idiom that means "to be doing something at all time"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means "to be doing something at all time"? Like the antonym of the expression "stay in the backseat (at all time)", something that means "be proactive at all time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [**as busy as a bee**](https://www.theidioms.com/as-busy-as-a-bee/):

> [The Idioms]
>
> - very busy
> - hard working
> - totally full of activity and on the go
> - in a purposeful and pleasant way
>
> The children are **as busy as bees**, trying to complete their costumes before the concert tomorrow night.
>
> You never have time to hang out with your friends anymore. What has you **as busy as a bee**?
>
> My husband is **as busy as a bee** with the merger at work. He will be unable to join me at the fundraiser but I will attend without him.

---

Lots of energy directed at nothing in particular would be [**ants in pants**](https://www.theidioms.com/ants-in-pants/):

> [The Idioms]
>
> - be extremely restless
> - be very excited or worried about something
> - uneasy, impatient or anxious
> - not able to keep still
> - extremely agitated or uneasy about something
>
> The children are always jumping out of their seats and running all around, They seems to have **ants in their pants**.
>
> She was very excited to be going to the party that night and had **ants in her pants** all day.
>
> His five year old daughter has **ants in her pants**. She keeps running around never can keep still for moment.

---

It's interesting that both of these idioms are analogies to situations involving animals.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'always' will satisfy your requirements.

Merriam-Webster defines it as:

1 : at all times : INVARIABLY
always smiling
2 : FOREVER
will love you always

So you would say, "Always stay in the back seat," or "Always be proactive."

If you are trying to imply that someone is always doing something (always annoying you, always finding fault with you, always humming), or always doing something in exactly the same way, you could use 'constantly.'

"They are constantly playing the radio."

"They constantly walk from the front door to the back door."

[Merriam-Webster - Always](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/always)

[Merriam-Webster - Constantly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constantly)